# Text from database - convert to html

Tags: html, database

I've got an text from my database and I want to convert it into HTML code.
In my database the new lines are saved, but when I query it and echo it to my html code, there are no new lines, because I need to get some 
 codes in.

I've got this but this doesn't seem to work:
`$html = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $html);`

Thanks for any further help.

Comment: which language are you planning to use?

Comment: `this doesn't seem to work`.  Why not?  What happens?  Looks pretty OK to me.

Comment: Note that you should really be replacing with `<br />`, though I doubt that is causing it not to work.

Comment: <br /> fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
$html = nl2br($html);
```